# Java socket works only for one client, blocked after server accept

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem with my client/server program, which is blocked after one client is connected. My one client can communicate with my server, but when I try to connect another, the second can't connect. I never see my 'ok' on my console:

```
public class Server{
  private Map<Integer,ThreadClient > mapThreads;
  private ServerSocket serveur ;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try{
      Serveur serv = new Server();
      serv.setServer( new ServerSocket(4786,2));

      while (true)
      {
        serv.getMapThreads().put(new ThreadClient(serv.getServer().accept(),serv);
        System.out.println("ok");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }

class ThreadClient implements Runnable
{
  private Thread t;
  private Socket socket;
  private ObjectOutputStream oos ;
  private ObjectInputStream ois;
  private Serveur server;

  public ThreadClient(Socket s, Server serv ) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    server = serv;
    socket=s;
    try{
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException e){ }

    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      while(true){
        // send and recev message
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e){ }
}
```

Comment: There's a missing closing brace. I'd guess that it should be immediately before the start of the ThreadClient class, unless the ThreadClient class is intended to be contained within the Server class, in which case the closing brace is missing from the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the construction of the object streams out of the constructor and into the `run()` method. The process implies I/O with the peer so it shouldn't be carried out in the `accept()` thread.

Comment: i should instanciate it when i serv.accept() and give him 2 arguments object streams ? Can u show me ?!

Comment: public void run()
  {
    try {

            
           oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
           ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     while(true){}

Comment: Because i did it and it dont work, move it our of thread constuctor and it dont work, i put the declaration of ois et oos on the main

Comment: @gsi None of that makes any sense. If you do it the way I said it will work. It's been working for me for 22+ years. If you do it in the accept thread you will have the same problem you have now, for the same reason. You can't do it in your `main()` method because you don't have the client socket yet.